# Invoking and controlling vibration using Swift and iOS8

Tags: swift, ios8, vibration

How can I invoke vibration using Swift and control its duration? Also what other parameters can be defined? I would like to invoke a very short vibration using Swift.

I tried the following function:

```
func () {
  AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
}
```

but I get this error:

```
'Int' is not convertible to 'SystemSoundID'
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I have the same issue but using `1352` instead of `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` works for me.

```
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1352)
```

The above solution was used as a temporary workaround. As pointed out by many others, it is better to use `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))` as the above solution is not fail proof.

Comment: While your code might (or not) work it would be great if you add a brief explanation about the problem and how does your code solve it. As is it does not provide a full answer according to [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This seems not like a good way to solve this, the answer by @Mark is more robust because it uses the constant and not the value.

Comment: **This solution is dangerous! Do not use it!** Apple may change the id (`1352`) at any time, so it's highly recommended to use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))`.

Comment: For example, `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` is now (Mar 2015) `4095`. Wish the docs showed that the casting is required!

Answer (score 26):

This would be a better solution:

`AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))`